# Do I need to have identical user account on different domains to run a net use command via batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a Task Scheduler task that runs a batch file which copies a file from server1 to server2 on a different domain.

Note:The scheduled task is running on Domain_A using user accounts created to run auto processes.

**Task Scheduler Task:**

Run under Domain_A\user1

**Batch file commands/steps**
A) `net use q: \\shared drive\abc /user:Domain_A\user1 password1`

B) `net use w: \\server2\qwe /user:Domain_B\user2 password2`

C) `copy q:\*.txt w:\`

Command A runs without any issues and the drive gets mapped, however, command B fails. I added errorlevel and got 1.

If I run this command directly in cmd, it runs and drive gets mapped. However, I am using my personal account to run the cmd (Let's call that "master_user") and not the generic accounts created for auto running tasks (eg. user1 and user2). My account ("master_user") exist on both Domain_A and Domain_B.

My questions are,

**1) If you are trying to map a drive from Domain_B is it necessary to have the user1 account on that domain?**

My logic is, because user1 does not exist on other domain the cmd command is failing at step (B) since user1 is used to run cmd.

**2) What could I try to achieve the desired result?**

Comment: try https://serverfault.com. Also add info about the relationship between the two domains. Domains can exist in trees of domains with trust between them.

Comment: please post the error message. Also, verify drive letter availability before mapping. Tear-down drives mapping always.

Comment: Maybe bypass the problem by using `openssh` implementation and use the `scp` command for secure transfer using encryption keys and no passwords. You will have to maintain the passwords update in your script.

Comment: @Dudi Boy, There is no error. Although it is not included in my script here, I clear the drive letter before using it.

Comment: Since you asked this question on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/969943) meanwhile, you should delete this one...